# Geometry Node - Extrude Mesh is not solid

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm doing a pretty cool geometry node tutorial for blender 3.1 right now and can't find my mistake.

Why are my mesh stones not closed? Anyone see my mistake?

[image]

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA13LPCZ3dM

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, but [as noted in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/extrude_mesh.html), the *Extrude Mesh* node works a bit different than the extrude operation in *Edit Mode*:

> The operations are similar to the extrude tools in mesh edit mode, though there are some differences. Most importantly, the node never keeps the back-faces of the extrusion in place, they are always removed.

You can use a *Join Geometry* node to add the original faces to the extruded ones. You might also want to flip the originals' normals first and then merge the vertices by distance to get a manifold geometry:

[image]

In this example, the "Face Orientation" overlay is on, so the red color indicates the backsides of the original faces. *Flip Faces* node is muted (<kbd>M</kbd>); once that's unmuted, faces would turn blue/outward.

Comment: Infact,in his video,rock is also not closed, we can calculate the vertices,lines and faces shown in his video and prove that.

Comment: I hadn't actually checked the video, but as I skim it now, yes, at 13:30 mark for instance, you can see that the rocks don't have back faces.

Comment: @Kuboa that worked out thanks! At 13:30 it seems hollow indeed! but than I might have another problem because my nosie texture (7:30) was not working... I#ll try it with your solution now. Maybe I've to open another question after lunch if I#m stucked again. thank you anyway!

Comment: I still feel like something's missing here (I mean from a development standpoint, not your answer which is the correct one imo), because even if you join the geometry with the flipped original faces, the vertices aren't actually connected with each other so operations like boolean will fail in some cases. So either having the weld modifier implemented in GN or a "keep original faces" toggle on the Extrude mesh node would be cool.

Comment: @Gorgious I make a demo,extrude a plane to be a cube, Vertex/Edge/Face shows 8/12/5, after join Geometry，it shows 12/16/6, you are right.

Comment: @Gorgious Doesn't Weld modifier simply merge vertices by distance, just in a modifier form? I didn't know there was a difference so I'm surprised. Here's a video where I'm looking at the indices before and after the merge node, and indeed the duplicates get eliminated: https://i.imgur.com/6ABPArg.gif Are you saying the GN is somehow still aware of them having actually separate sources and that can have some technical side effects resulting in failed booleans etc? And that's not a bug, but a limitation only a new Weld node could get rid of?

Comment: Though I agree, I'm actually surprised the Extrude node was released without a "Keep originals" toggle. Maybe they had a good reason for it.

Comment: @Gorgious, but I find out that, if I add the node Merge by Distance,everything is OK.

Comment: @Kuboå, the reason is, I think, it's easy to add a face, but it's difficult to delete a face.

Comment: Oh man talk about a brainfart I actually didn't know there was a merge by distance node and I completely ommited it from your screenshot (and your answer...). So yeah I think the design here is to CTRL - G these nodes and rename the group "Solidify" and you're almost good to go feature wise

Comment: Haha, that's a relief, I thought I wasn't aware of some crucial difference. Phew.