# How can I fill both ends of a curve using Geometry Notes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

How can I fill both ends of a curve using Geometry Notes?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If, instead of extruding a filled curve, you use *Curve > Convert to Mesh*:

[image]

Cap-filling is already provided as an option.

Comment: (Remember to set flat shading - "Set Shade Smooth" node)

Comment: A much better suggestion than mine. I knew there was a 'fill caps' somewhere, but blanked on it. My newbie flag is unfurled and flapping wave-texturally in simulated wind.

Comment: @SamMitee yours answered generally by extrusion. I wouldn't say Markus's was better. They are just different ‍♂️.

Comment: @shmuel echo that :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation for this from an earlier post here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/256602/181042

The short version is that the extrude mesh node does not preserve the back face. You have to copy/flip it, then merge it with the original geometry to restore it.

Changing the relevant part of your node tree to something more like this might help:
[image: node_tree_exmpl]